# How to process (Inserting in db) incoming streaming data in php?

Tags: php, guzzle

I am continuously getting streaming twitter data from gnip by guzzle library in json formate.

Below is my code

```
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
    $url =https://stream.gnip.com:443/accounts/{account_name}/publishers/twitter/streams/track/dev.json";
    $username = '*****';
    $password = '*****';
    $headers = array('Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip');

    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $client->setDefaultOption('headers/Accept-Encoding', 'gzip');
    $data = $client->get($url, ['auth' => [$username, $password]]))
    {
      $tdata = $data->getBody();
     //here i am getting json data continuously,that I have to insert in my db.
     //I have written my code to insert in db and it is inserting in db but after some      time it will not insert in db.


    }
```

So please suggest me ,if there are other best method or some php library available.

Answer (score -2):

For best practice, you can implement a rest service for inserting data in db. Let say you have a rest service;

```
/data/insert
```

You will send each streamed data to that service like;

```
functiond insertData($data) {}
    $url = 'http://domain.com/data/insert';
    $fields = array(
                            'field1' => urlencode($data["field1"]),
                            'field2' => urlencode($data["field1"]),
                            'field3' => urlencode($data["field1"])
                    );

    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { 
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
    }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

When you get stream data, just run this function, and do not care about how to insert data in db. Maybe, you can handle data insertion part in service side.